# parse PHP curl response as array?

Tags: php, curl

SOLUTION
Edited with Solution.

Don't know If I have to answer, or edit, or what.

The problem was that the service sometimes answers headers, and others body too.

In my specific situation, I solved using this snippets founded here on SO.

With this function I get the body of the answer.

```
function get_body_from_curl_response($response){
    list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
    return $body;
}
```

And with this function, I get an assoc array of the header.

```
function get_headers_from_curl_response($response)
{
    $headers = array();
    $header_text = substr($response, 0, strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n"));
    foreach (explode("\r\n", $header_text) as $i => $line)
        if ($i === 0)
            $headers['http_code'] = $line;
        else
        {
            list ($key, $value) = explode(': ', $line);

            $headers[$key] = $value;
        }
    return $headers;
}
```

--
Initial problem.

I'm trying to communicate with a REST service, but don't understand how to parse the response. From python samples of the service, I see is very easy to manage the response similar to an array, but from php I just get a large text I have to parse in some way.

The answer is something like
http://www.valentina-db.com/docs/dokuwiki/v6/doku.php?id=valentina:articles:vserver_rest&s[]=rest

There are some way to parse curl output like urllib2 in python does?

### UPDATE

My code

```
$data = array("user" => "sa", "password" => md5("sa"));

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/rest');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));

$result = curl_exec($ch2);

echo 'Result <br>';
var_dump  ( $result ) ;
echo '<br>--------- <br>';

$json_answer = json_decode( $result, true );
echo ' <br> json answer <br>';
print_r ( $json_answer );
echo '<br>--------- <br>';
echo ' <br> json error <br>';

print_r ( json_last_error_msg() );

echo '<br>--------- <br>';

curl_close($ch2);
```

and this is the output

```
Result
irrelevant_path\index.php:1155: string(140) "HTTP/1.1 201 Created Location: /rest/session_b4b8e5ce3f709c452b3dfc94e9273a0d; Set-Cookie: sessionID=b4b8e5ce3f709c452b3dfc94e9273a0d; "
---------

json answer

---------

json error
Syntax error
---------
```

Comment: It looks like it's returning JSON-formatted data strings (as most RESTful API's do), so [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is what I thought, but is not working. I updated with the code used and the output.

Comment: Add a `pre` tag around the `$result` and repost the output. It looks like you're getting a redirect, not a JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are getting answer in JSON which you can convert to array by using

json_decode($json_data)
it will convert json data to array format.

hope it helps

Comment: Actually it'll convert it to an object. For an array you have to pass true in as the second param.